# Is it possbile to monitor Cosmos metrics from OMS and setup alerts

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-oms

In Metric section of Cosmos we have Number of requests, Max Consumed RU/s per partition Key by collection. How to I send this to OMS so that I can have a nice consolidated dashboard and set altering system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FYI,
[OMS portal is transitioned to Azure Portal for Log Analytics Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-oms-portal-transition)*

**The OMS portal will be officially retired on January 15, 2019**

Back to your question

Yes, OMS/Log Analytics can be used to collect metrics/Logs from Cosmos DB.

Just configure the `Diagnostics logs` to the `Log Analytics` from your cosmos DB

[image]

[image]

**[Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging#turn-on-logging-in-the-azure-portal)**